# Confusion matrix for ranges

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I have two data frames, first on is my predicted values in range format:

```
structure(c("(-3,2]", "(2,7]", "(-3,2]", "(2,7]", "(-3,2]", 
"(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", 
"(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", 
"(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(2,7]"), .Dim = c(5L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Q", "Y", "S", "L", "X")))
```

and other one is the reference values:

```
structure(c("(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", 
"(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", 
"(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", 
"(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]", "(-3,2]"), .Dim = c(5L, 
 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Q", "Y", "S", "L", "X")))
```

I have tried couple of ways, but I could not figure out how to perform a confusion matrix. Can anyone please help me? Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Also, it looks to be inconsistent: `"(2,7]"` (no-space) versus `"( 2,7]"` (with-space). If you are generating these by hand, better make sure you are being consistent. (If not by hand, then you're going to have a confusing or at least misleading confusion matrix.)

Comment: I want to get confusion matrix for each pair of predicted and reference columns. No I do not generated by hand, it can be due to modification and adjustment.

Comment: If those are decimal values in European format then a confusion matrix makes no sense since it is a method appropriate for discrete values. If it's not than it would appear to be some sort of factor values. Suggest you [edit] the question to replace that print output you have now with the results of `dput()` on each of the objects.

Comment: No they are ranges. The predicted ranges and the given ranges.

Comment: I edited, please note that the data may be subject to change.

Comment: I suggest you address @DavidHeckmann's question ... for instance, a confusion matrix might be *one matrix per variable* (each of Q, Y, S, L, and X), showing expected on the left and actual on the top.

Comment: There is `caret::confusionMatrix`, perhaps that is what you need?

Comment: Yes, for each pair of columns with same names, (lets say Q_predicted, and Q_actual), the actual values are bins (the given references) that comes on the left, the predicted values comes on the top.  At intersection of each row and column the number of predicted cases are set. This is a sample of my data, which may makes it misleading. I tried carret, as I told could not figure out how to build confusion matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There cannot be much "confusion" if all the values of one of the objects are all the same but here's code that should work for a more complete listing:

```
table(unlist(dat2),unlist(dat1))

         (-3,2] (2,7]
  (-3,2]     22     3
```

With your earlier `print`-ed data I got:

```
table(unlist(dat2),unlist(dat1))

         (-3,2] (2,7]
  (-3,2]     21     0
  (2,7]       2     2
```

If they had been factors you might not have succeeded. Might have needed to run `lapply` using `as.character` to coerce to "character".

Comment: Thanks it helps a lot, I will try your suggestions to see what happens.